# ESRI Collector app- Offline record collection limit

Tags: arcgis-collector, offline, data-collection

I am wanting to find out what the maximum number of records people have collected while being offline on the ESRI Collector app. I am operating on an Ipad with a 64 GB capacity.

Has anyone load tested the Collector app offline or know what the limit could be?

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure the limit is variable on the device storage. If there are no images or videos being taken with the collection would be fairly large amount

[HERE](http://I%20am%20pretty%20sure%20the%20limit%20is%20variable%20on%20the%20device%20storage.%20If%20there%20are%20no%20images%20or%20videos%20being%20taken%20with%20the%20collection%20would%20be%20fairly%20large%20amount) is a Geonet thread discussing a similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

As [commented by @BenSNadler](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/260901/esri-collector-app-offline-record-collection-limit#comment413441_260901):

> There is a limit to the size of the vector data you can download and
>   manage per map. I think it is around 2gb. this does not include
>   basemaps